# How to use enclose node package to generate executable file in Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, exe

In my current project, I am using AM2302 Temperature Sensor which is connected to GPIO pin on Raspberry Pi. The code for Temperature  Sensor in Node.js as shown below:

```
var sensorLib = require('node-dht-sensor'); 
var mqtt=require('mqtt'); 
var client=mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883');  
var sensor = {
    initialize: function () {
        //Developer: By default TemperatureSensor is connected to GPIO4 (i.e. Pin 7)
        return sensorLib.initialize(22, 4); 
    },
    read: function () {
        var readout = sensorLib.read();
        var data={"tempValue":readout.temperature.toFixed(2),"unitOfMeasurement":"C"}; 
    client.publish('tempMeasurement',JSON.stringify(data));  
       console.log("Publishing tempMeasurement: TemperatureSensor");
        setTimeout(function () {
            sensor.read();
        }, 5000);
    }
}; 
if (sensor.initialize()) {
    sensor.read();
} else {
    console.warn('Failed to initialize TemperatureSensor');
}
```

I want to convert this **Node.js file into .exe file using enclose node package**. I converted several Node.js file into .exe file using enclose node package in windows. Here when I give command `sudo enclose TemperatureSensor.js -o TemperatureSensor.exe` in terminal of raspberry pi it doesn't display any error or warning but doesn't generate TemperatureSensor.exe. I can't convert this file into .exe in windows as it have several dependencies. Am I missing something?? Is there any alternative way to convert Node.js file into .exe in Raspberry Pi ??

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert this Node.js file into .exe file using enclose node package.

May I ask why? I've deployed Node apps onto Raspberry Pi's before and ran them as node apps with no issues.

Comment: I have provided above program for reference that is for Temperature Sensor. Node.js is light weight server side scripting language so if we want Raspberry pi to act as server than it is easily possible with Node.js without any extra effort.